# How can I limit the X and Y offsets of a car with a max_speed value while taking its angle into account?

Tags: python, math, game-physics, trigonometry, angle

## Context :

I have this game where I control a car in a top-down view. I use multiple variables to move it.

- The `MAX_SPEED` is `5`. (meaning it can move 5px per tick at most)
- The `FORWARD_ACC` (for acceleration) is `0.25` (meaning the speed goes up by a quarter of a px per tick when accelerating).
- The `speed` of the car (which is a vector `[0,0]` : `[x offset, y offset]`).
- The `acceleration` of the car (which is a vector too `[x acc, y acc]`).
- Finally, the `angle` of the car (which is in radians).

Those variables allow me to assign an acceleration to the car according to its angle in top-down view.

I calculate the `acceleration` value with trigonometry : `acceleration = [cos(angle)*FORWARD_ACC, sin(angle)*FORWARD_ACC]`.

So, when accelerating (`0.25`px) at an `angle` of pi/2 radians (which is going down, so 90 degrees in pygame), my `acceleration` vector will be `[0, 0.25]`. when going at an `angle` of pi radians (which is going left, so 180 degrees in pygame), my `acceleration` vector will be `[-0.25, 0]`.

I then add the `acceleration` to the speed with this function :

```py
def add_acc_to_speed(speed, acceleration):
    returned_speed = [speed[0]+acceleration[0], speed[1]+acceleration[1]]
    return(returned_speed if abs(returned_speed[0])+abs(returned_speed[1])<MAX_SPEED else speed)
```

This function was supposed to make it so that the sum of `|x offset| + |y offset|` could not exceed `MAX_SPEED`. This way the car cannot go faster than `5`px.

## What's wrong :

The issue is that this function, as you can see, returns the passed `speed` parameter if the sum is higher than 5. A side effect of this is that the new `acceleration`, which is passed as a parameter and **depends on the angle of the car**, is not taken into account.

Basically, let's say your car goes right for a while and rapidly reaches max speed. if you try to turn to the down direction, your car won't turn and rather go kind of sideways **as long as your Y offset from the acceleration variable is not higher than the x offset**. so for example if I have `[0.19, 0.16]` I'd still go right for a good 30 seconds before the `0.16` starts being taken into account (and only because the 0.19 is not 0.25 so the x offset is slowly reducing, **allowing more "space" in the window I allowed**, which is limited by max_speed.

Now let's say you turn a little more and your `acceleration` value is now `[0.17,0.18]`. Since the Y offset of your acceleration is now higher than the X offset, the car will make a turn as intended.

This leads to strange, sharp turns and a car mostly going up, down, left or right :
[image: sharp turns.]

## TL;DR :

the limit I put on my speed vector makes it so that one of the offsets needs to lower in order for the other one to go up, which won't happen as long as the one that needs to lower has a higher `acceleration` value.

## **What did I already try ?**

- Setting an individual limit of `MAX_SPEED` on each of the offsets (this leads to both offsets being able to go up to 5 (`[5,5]`) and the car going WAY TOO FAST when going diagonally).
- Setting an individual limit of `MAX_SPEED//2` on each of the offsets (this solves the diagonal issue but the car now goes only 2.5 even when facing up, down, left or right (`[2.5,0]` for example).
- I did not try that yet but maybe dynamically modifying the `MAX_SPEED` value so that I have a middle ground between both those attempts ?

I know that it's more complicated than just setting an integer as a limit, and that my mistake that leads to those sharp turns is returning the passed `speed` parameter and thus not taking the new `acceleration` and `angle` into account.

I hope I explained myself clearly ! feel free to ask further questions or for code snippets :)

## EDIT :

Following @SimonGoater's comment, my car can now go in circles, but it seems the issue of the car not actually turning until the lower offset's `acceleration` value takes over the other one's is still affecting my game.

Here you can see the `acceleration` values on top, then the `speed` value underneath it, in the brackets. As you can see, the car is facing the bottom right corner of the screen, and still won't turn because of the function returning the passed `speed` parameter (and thus not taking the angle of the car into account) when the returned speed exceeds `MAX_SPEED`.

[image: car going almost completely right even though it's facing the bottom right corner of the picture]
(note that if the speed says `0.05` where the acceleration is `0.17`, it's because there is also friction in my game, which can be ignored in this question.)

Comment: Don't you want return(returned_speed if returned_speed[0]*returned_speed[0]+returned_speed[1]*returned_speed[1]<MAX_SPEED*MAX_SPEED else speed) to use the actual length of the vector (squared in this case)?

Comment: I've been reading about squares and square roots for a while when trying to solve this and I've never really understood why are we using squared values ? Would you care to explain, please ?

Comment: @SimonGoater Well, that seems to have done it ! I'd really like to understand why though, but it feels refreshing to finally have my car making circles instead of those weird diamonds . Mind posting this as an answer so I can accept it, since it solved my issue ?

Edit : It solved my 'squares when turning' issue, but it seems I still have this problem where my car won't turn because of the x_offset not leaving enough 'space' for the y_offset to grow in. I'll edit my question.

Comment: I wasn't sure before, but now I have an idea of what you're missing: do read up about vectors and scalars. It's all good when you're just moving up-down-left-right, but you need to indirectly use the Pythagorean theorem when it comes to other directions in a 2D plane (also called Cartesian plane) — and this is where squares and square roots come in. Vectors are beautiful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calculating what is know as Manhattan Distance abs(x) + abs(y) for the length of your speed vector. You should be using the normal Cartesian Distance sqrt(x^2 + y^2). Since your maximum doesn't change, it is more efficient to compare the squares directly since square root calculations are relatively slow. I think for a naive solution, you just need to change the return line

```
return(returned_speed if returned_speed[0]*returned_speed[0]
  +returned_speed[1]*returned_speed[1]
  <MAX_SPEED*MAX_SPEED else speed)
```

Better still use a constant for MAX_SPEED*MAX_SPEED. It might be better if the length exceeds MAX_SPEED, that the vector is scaled to the maximum length rather than just returning the previous vector. This can be achieved by multiplying both components by

```
MAX_SPEED / sqrt(returned_speed[0]*returned_speed[0]
  +returned_speed[1]*returned_speed[1])
```

if the denominator exceeds MAX_SPEED.

Something to consider, is that velocity is the term usually used for the rate of change of position, and 'speed' is normally the scalar length of that vector.

Comment: after going for a bite and getting back on, I read through your answer a couple times, and finally understood. That's some clever tricks ! certainly higher level math than what I can come up with on my own. It works wonders, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

NOTE: This is not a comprehensive answer. It is intended to help you in figuring out what went wrong, because I'll need a lot more context (and time :p ) to give an exact answer.

I'm assuming that the `add_acc_to_speed(speed, acceleration)` function is being called every tick.

Why don't you try imposing a limit on:

`new_speed = math.sqrt(((speed[0]+acceleration[0])**2 + (speed[1]+acceleration[1])**2))`,

which is basically `square_root(x_component^2 + y_component^2)`.

This is the actual speed of the car, and this will deal with points #1 and #2 under "What did I already try?".

If the value of this speed after adding acceleration is beyond 5, you can return the x and y components of the velocity after taking the angle into account by:

`x_comp = float(format(math.cos(angle),".2f")) # ".2f" for 2 decimal places`

`y_comp = float(format(math.sin(angle),".2f"))`

These x_comp and y_comp values will be the float values that give max speed of 5. You can modify their type as per your needs.

NOTE: You can either modify the function and add "angle" as a parameter, or extract the angle from the acceleration using inverse tan `math.atan()` function on the ratio of y and x components of the acceleration.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I'll look into this. If you need me to give you some more context on anything, feel free to ask !